# How do I avoid needing to initialize a member object in the initialization list?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, initialization

I am writing a C++ application that makes use of plenty of child objects nested within one 'root' object.

Each of these needs to be initialized in a specific order, with various operations being done *between* each initialization, and sometimes needing to have previously-initialized ones as arguments to each other.

However, my compiler is forcing me to initialize these in the constructor's initializer list, insisting that initializing *within* the constructor is not enough. For example, I could not do the following:

```
SomeThing::SomeThing() {
    int argGottenByLibraryCall;
    someLibraryCallToGetArg(&argGottenByLibraryCall);
    m_ChildObject = ChildClass(argGottenByLibraryCall);
}
```

I have taken to implementing a post-creation initializer function instead:

```
SomeThing::SomeThing() : m_ChildObject() {
    int argGottenByLibraryCall;
    someLibraryCallToGetArg(&argGottenByLibraryCall);
    m_ChildObject.Initialize(argGottenByLibraryCall);
}
```

This, however, seems like a poor practice for me to follow. Is there a better way of making my compiler (VC++ 2017) accept initialization within the constructor body?

Comment: *"For example, I could not do the following"*. Should be possible if `ChildClass` has a move/copy constructor...

Answer (score 2):

> This, however, seems like a poor practice for me to follow.

The poor practice is **not using initialization lists**. They allow you to mark your data members as `const` and also ensure that they are initialized.

The correct way to solve your problem is to restructure your code so that `m_ChildObject` has a proper constructor that can be used in the member initialization list.

If that is not possible, wrap your initialization logic in a function and use that in the member initialization list:

```
ChildObjectType makeChildObject() {
    int argGottenByLibraryCall;
    someLibraryCallToGetArg(&argGottenByLibraryCall);

    ChildObjectType result;
    result.Initialize(argGottenByLibraryCall);
    return result;
}

// ...

SomeThing::SomeThing() : m_ChildObject(makeChildObject()) { }
```